# sql query grouping of data

Tags: java, sql, database

i need some help with a sql query. I have a table called 'table1' and it looks as follows ;

```
ID            Time               Total 
1             12/12/12           100
2             12/12/12           10
3             12/12/12           10
1             12/12/12           100
3             12/12/12           10
```

I am populating the above data in a jtable. I want to only display ONE instance of the same ID but calculate the total between them. How is this possible? (if the ID is same, then only display it once but calculate the total).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to display time?

```
select ID, Time, Sum(Total) as Total
from Table1
group by ID, Time
```

If not,

```
select ID, Sum(Total) as Total
from Table1
group by ID
```

Answer (score 1):

something like

select id, sum(total) from table1 group by id

should give you a start

Answer (score 1):

This should do it;

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Total) AS Total
FROM table1
GROUP BY ID;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a35ba/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, Time, SUM(Total) As Total From Table GROUP BY ID
```